# Reference a MasterPage property

Tags: asp.net, inheritance, master-pages

I have a master page with the following code:

```
public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public SqlConnection cnx;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
 
    }
}
```

How do I reference the public `SqlConnection` `cnx` property from an `aspx.cs` file that uses this master page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your master page:

```
    public SqlConnection CnxInMasterPage
    {
        get { return this.cnx; }
    }
```

In Content page (first add using so you can reference 'MasterPage' type)

```
var cnx = ((MasterPage)Master).CnxInMasterPage;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options:

1. cast the `Master` property to your `MasterPage` type and proceed from there.
2. Include `<%@ MasterType virtualpath="~/path/to/master.master" %>` in your aspx file which will strongly type the Master property.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare an interface `IMyMasterPage` and put the property there. Allow your master page to implement it.

Then you can do this on your page.

```
var myMasterPage = this.MasterPage as IMyMasterPage
```

Comment: or if you're never going to have more than one master page you can just cast to the MasterPage class itself, but the interface makes it easier to support more than one (or more than one with different code-behinds).

Comment: Can I ask why you recommend this instead of simply typecasting to your existing master page type, or using the `MasterType` directive?

Comment: @Jonathan Wood - for the reason Rup gave.

Comment: An interface is not going to solve the problem.  Also, there is no need to over design.  An interface should be used when an interface is needed, not if there is a possibility that an interface could/might/maybe be useful